# HTA project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, hta

Is there a way to create HTA project in Visual Studio 2013 that allows straightforward step by stepdebugging?

Comment: Not that I know of (and I have done some HTA development in Visual Studio). But I'd be happy to be proven wrong.